# sharepoint publishing feature changed my main navigation bar

Tags: publishing, feature-activation, global-navigation

I enabled sharepoint publishing feature, because I needed anchor feature. For some reason, this changed my navigation bar.

I do not know what to call it, but the first link was moved above the other links and cannot be moved/changed. I also had the submenu attached to that link and it disappeared. Other links seem to be locked to MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels of 1.

Can I regain previous navigation without turning off publishing again?

Answer (score 0):

> Can I regain previous navigation without turning off publishing again?

No, but you can generally recreate it in Settings, Site Settings, Navigation. You can have two levels of navigation, but you will need to reconfigure it. If you post screen captures of the before and after, we can offer some suggestions. (Yes, I know you probably don't have the "before" available anymore!) Or, a text example of the structure you had.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I have attached a picture to the menu structure: https://imgur.com/a/F1RiX